# Book/reference to practice stochastic calculus and PDE for interviews

Tags: stochastic-calculus, differential-equations

I will be going through interview processes in next months.
I would like to have a book/reference to practice the manipulation of PDE, and stochastic calculus questions.
For example, I get a bit confused when I am deriving the Fokker-Planck equation, as PDE manipulation is necessary.
I am seeking for a book/reference containing exercises and solutions, so I can practice.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: [Shreve vol II](https://www.amazon.com/dp/144192311X) chaper 6 "Connections with Partial Differential Equations" has exercises on Kolmogorov backward equation (#6.8) and on Kolmogorov forward equation also called Fokker-Planck  (#6.9). If you search, you can find many versions of answers to exercises, e.g. by [Yan Zeng](http://yyschools.com/courses/FinancialEconomics/shreve%20solution%20manual.pdf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may like:

[*Probability and Stochastic Calculus Quant Interview Questions* by Ivan Matić, Radoš Radoičić, Dan Stefanica](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1734531223)

[*150 Most Frequently Asked Questions on Quant Interviews*, Second Edition by Dan Stefanica, Radoš Radoičić, Tai-Ho Wang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/097975769X)

[*Heard on the Street: Quantitative Questions from Wall Street Job Interviews* by Timothy Falcon Crack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0994103867)

[*A Practical Guide To Quantitative Finance Interviews* by Xinfeng Zhou](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BL7QGYV2)

[*Quant Job Interview Questions And Answers* by Mark Joshi, Nick Denson, Andrew Downes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0987122827)

[*Cracking the Finance Quant Interview: 51 Interview Questions and Solutions* by Jean Peyre](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08D4F8RJP)